Is the reciprocal vector G is added to the wave vector crossing the 1st brillouin zone and the solution just happens to explain the phonon behaviour?

I know a little that because of periodic nature of crystal and so potential, according to bloch theorem only wave vectors inside 1st brillouin zone are unique
So when the addition of 2 phonon wave vectors give a third one crossing 1st brillouin zone then it is translated by a integer multiple of reciprocal vector G till it is inside 1st brillouin zone
1) Also from figure I am thinking that online those components of resultant vector which cross the brillouin zone are reduced
In this case the Kx vector.
2) And my main question is is this all reciprocal lattice and umklapp process representation of quantum behaviour of phonons and lattice is accepted just because it happens to be in agreement with experiments?
I get the part that bloch theorem must be satisfied,
So the modulo of wave vector is taken in account
